# MySQL: Get the max values for specified name

Tags: mysql

I have a table sometable:

```
name | math   | history  | status  
-----------------------------
jon  |   80   |   90     | 1  
alex |   90   |   70     | 1  
alex |   87   |   80     | 1  
jon  |   78   |   80     | 0  
alex |   90   |   60     | 1  
jon  |   30   |   100    | 0  
emile|   99   |   89     | 0
```

what i want to do is get a row that name=alex, status=1 and have the maximal value for math, and then history for rows that satisfied. So the result will be

```
alex |   90   |   70     | 1
```

I try code like:

```
select * from sometable where (name=$name and status=1) order by math DESC, history DESC
```

I got what i expect, since i can get the first row only of mysql_fetch_array.
But imagine how much the row in mysql_fetch array.

Yes, my code isnt false, but it is not enough "sophisticated" since it fetch many rows,Can anybody give a solution?
Thanks. ^^

Comment: What does "*imagine how much the row in mysql_fetch array*" mean?

Comment: yes, i fetch the result of the query into a mysql_fetch_array(im using php);

in the sample above, there are only 3 rows, but in real database, it can take many rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you need only one row - use `LIMIT 1` clause:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM tblname
   WHERE name = 'alex'
     AND status = 1
ORDER BY math DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks, ^^. Im sorry because forget it.
Btw, it must be ORDER BY math DESC, history DESC LIMIT 1